# Properties of iid continuous random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X, Y, Z$ be iid continuous random variables. Show that $P[X <
Y ] = 0.5$. Calculate $P[X < Y < Z]$.

My try: We know that for continuous random variable, $P(X=y)=0$, i.e. Probability at a point is zero. Hence, $P(X>y)+P(X<y)=1$. But how to show that $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)=0.5.$ Can you suggest a book to study this concepts?.

Comment: Hint: What is $P(X=Y)$? Why shouldn't $P(X>Y)$ have the _same_ value as $P(X<Y)$? After all, $X$ and $Y$ are iid, and there is nothing to distinguish $P(X>Y)$ from $P(X<Y)$. Finally, do you agree that $$P(X>Y) + P(X=Y) + P(X<Y) = 1?$$

Comment: Will the $P[X<Y<Z]$ be $1/3$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate No.  $\Bbb P(X<Y<Z)$ ${=\Bbb P(X<Z<Y)\\=\Bbb P(Y<X<Z)\\=\Bbb P(Y<Z<X)\\=\Bbb P(Z<X<Y)\\=\Bbb P(Z<Y<X)\\= 1/6}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ooops! I am deleting my previous comment,